# Parse From Text File into String output

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So I have a text file called employees.txt that looks like this...

```
Billy Madderson, M, 34
Allison McGever, F, 32
Bill Nye, M, 35
```

I'm trying to write a sed script that will read in the text file then output it in the format
"< name > is a < gender >, and is < age > years old now."

I know I need to set the IFS=, but I'm stuck on how to place the information in the string. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I need to set the IFS=

I don't see why this would be necessary. As far as I know `sed` doesn't use `IFS` at all.

Replace the first `,` with `is a`, `M`/`F` by `man`/`woman`, the second `,` with `and is` and so on. The only tricky part is to only replace the `M`/`F` in the second column instead of the first `M`/`F` you come across. Luckily, after the second column there are no letters anymore, so that simplifies things.

```
sed 's/, M/ is a man/;s/, F/ is a woman/;s/, /, and is /;s/$/ years old now./' file
```

For your example the output is

```
Billy Madderson is a man, and is 34 years old now.
Allison McGever is a woman, and is 32 years old now.
Bill Nye is a man, and is 35 years old now.
```

Comment: What would happen if instead of 'M/F' for gender it became numbers? Like years with the company? So you had 13.5, 10.2, 11.8 added? How would that change because I'm assuming you can't search and use $ for both the age and years now? Sorry I'm just trying to figure sed out because I didn't think $ work for more than one case.

Comment: `$` is just the end of the line. I used it to *append* text to each line. If you add columns in the middle, that changes nothing on the `$` part. If you add columns at the end, you would have to insert `years old now` in another way, e.g. by replacing a `,`.